# mysql datetime format change using java for JasperReports generation

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReport's `iReport 4.5.0` designer to build my report. I am having one problem with the timestamp fields `startDate` and `endDate`. In my designer I changed the format of `startDate` and `endDate` using pattern.

But, **the problem is that when I export the report as .excel or .pdf it still gives me date in timestamp format,** not the format `YYYY-MM-dd`I had done in pattern.

my report generated with starDate as **2012-03-01 00:00:00.0** but I want my excel report to be have starDate in **2012-03-01** like `YYYY-MM-dd`.

Any solution you had, **I don't want to change my database type from datetime to date.**

My projectmain.jrxml file code is below mentioned:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="projectmain" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="pagelimit" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="pagestart" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from project limit $P{pagestart},$P{pagelimit}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="projectid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="enddate" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="projectdesc" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="projectname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="projecttitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="startdate" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="56">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="410" height="56"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Management Report Generation]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="28">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="28" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#666666"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Management Report Generation]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="29">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="144" height="29" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="144" y="0" width="158" height="29" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="302" y="0" width="151" height="29" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="16" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Start Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="453" y="0" width="102" height="29" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[End Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="29">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="144" height="29"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{projecttitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="d/M/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="453" y="0" width="102" height="29"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{enddate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="144" y="0" width="158" height="29"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectname}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="d/M/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="302" y="0" width="151" height="29"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{startdate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="60">
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="20" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="14" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="31">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="541" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Century" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Copyright Â© Project Management 2012 | Design by Kintudesigns.com]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Are `startDate` and `endDate` is really variables or they are fields? Can you post the snippet from the `jrxml` file (with `startDate`, `endDate` declaration and the sample of using this variables)?

Comment: @AlexK thanks for your response. I had updated my question and also added the projectmain.jrxml file to it. Say me any solution I can try to get it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to set [***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type) property for correct formatting in case export to Excel format.

This issue is very strange. You can add the variable of ***`java.text.DateFormat`*** type and use it like in this sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="datetime_format" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT date1, date2 FROM table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="date1" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="date2" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <variable name="dateFormat" class="java.text.DateFormat" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="194" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{dateFormat}.format($F{date1})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                <reportElement x="205" y="0" width="272" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

It is works for me. I have the correct data for both textFields (with using `DateFormat` and without it) for PDF and XLS.